# django one-to-many

Tags: django, list, model, many-to-one

Long story short: I have two models, and a database imported from XML. The model layout is as follows:

```
class A:
    ForgeinKey(B)

class B:
    list = {A1, A2 ... An}
```

Is there a replacement for {A1, A2 ... An} that would make B.list return a list of A's.

Edit: The idea is to have a field in B that lists all the A's that are pointing to it. I can't  seem to figure out how to call A.objects.* from inside B's definition. I don't even know if that's possible.

Edit2: Solved, thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: your short story does not explain what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want `B().list` to return the result of `SELECT * FROM A WHERE B_id = <B.id>`?

You have to use related_name, then:

```
class A(Model):
    b = ForeignKey(B, related_name='list')
```

Or, you can use the default name, "`B().A_set`"